# Installing Linux on an external hard drive and multibooting with Windows 7/8

Tags: linux, windows, external-hdd

I want to multi boot Linux (Fedora 19) with my two machines which use Windows 7 and 8. The Windows7 is a desktop, and the laptop is a Windows 8 machine.

I used my desktop to install Fedora 19 on the external drive. I can boot Fedora from the desktop but not the other machine. To be clear the portable machine can boot from USB hard disk, I've checked the BIOS.

I found that an easy way to boot Linux or any other OS is using an OS independent boot manager. I downloaded Boot-US and tried it out. However when I load it up and it shows the disks it says my desktops primary internal HDD is bootable. The other one, the external disk does not. I checked the help section for the program (specifically Linux Tip (2)) and it required that I edit Lilo.

I know Fedora 19 uses Grub 2 in place of Lilo and I wouldn't know how to safely edit either boot loader anyway.

Could somebody help me install this OS to my external Hard Disk and still be able to boot from that when on my desktop OR laptop?

[edit] I have a UEFI BIOS on both the desktop and the laptop. I installed Fedora 19 to the external hard disk by use of a LiveDVD.

To the contrary of what the comment below says Boot-US should be able to boot from almost anything. It recommends that you try your first boot from a diskette (something nobody uses anymore) or a CD. It can also be installed to the MBR on the Hard Disk but that could make the system impossible to boot if done wrong if I am correct in remembering.

Comment: Could you please give more information about the computer/laptop you are trying to run this on? So that we know whether it is UEFI based or not for example. 

Also from the quick look I had at Boot-US, it is expecting the partitions to be MBR based to be able to read, so how did you format your external hard drive? 
I would suggest you download GParted ISO and burn it to a CD or USB then boot it, connect your external USB then reformat your external HD as MBR, install fedora again and then try to boot from Boot-US.

Comment: I added some info about my two systems. Could you explain what you mean by "format your external HD as MBR?" and "Try to boot from Boot-US"? I cannot boot my External HD from it because the software does not recognize the HD as bootable. The software would allow you to install itself to a diskette or CD but my problem is that the HD is not bootable. I have nothing of value on said disk so I could definitely reinstall F19.

Comment: I suspect the reason for not detecting your external HD as bootable by Boot-US is the partition table type of the HD. Follow this forum post to figure out the type of Partition table you have in External HD, 
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/292184-32-partition-table. And tell us whether it is MBR or GPT.

Comment: use UNetBootIn to create bootable USB disks: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Actually I did get it to work. I had to enable a setting in my laptops BIOS. It was "Legacy Support". I was warned that my Laptop may not be able to boot if I did this and even had to enter a security code given to me on screen but after that all I had to do was plug in the external HD and it booted from that. I have a HP Envy Dv6 notebook. I realized that even if it wouldn't boot I could always go back into the BIOS and change it back. Thank you for offering your help though.